# Why this SQL query returns extra space?

Tags: sql

I am trying to undestand why the below query is returning extra space after '3'. This is a screenshot from on of the SQL quizes available online. I would expect 'C' to be the correct answer.  Is there anything that causes the extra space or might it be an error in the task?

[image: SQL Query]

Comment: IDK what database this is for but CHAR is usually a fixed size, I think you need to use VARCHAR or equivalent.  Tag question with database

Comment: Make sure the extra space isn't in the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `char` type always stores data for **all** of the allocated space. Therefore a `char(5)`, if it's not `null`, will always have `5` characters. If you store one character in the field the remaining four will be spaces.

Therefore the actual result will look like this:

```
King Kong (3    )
```

But in the context of HTML, multiple whitespace characters in sequence render by default as a single space, so you see this on the screen:

```
King Kong (3 )
```

To fix this to get the expected `King Kong (3)`, you could use `varchar(5)` instead of `char(5)` or alternatively call `rtrim()` before the final concatenation.

Comment: Being that this is a quiz with no real code running under the hood, just a screenshot of SMSS, do you think that the makers of the quiz didn't realize that 5 spaces in their answer `b` would show as a single space and that's what is causing the confusion? Like, the answer here is 1) There would be 4 spaces because of `Char(5)` 2) The makers of this quiz screwed up with how that is being displayed.

Comment: That's what it looks like.

Comment: @JNevill That's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is misleading because the answers are not displayed in such a way that whitespace is preserved, probably unintentionally. (Right-click the answer and use "inspect element" to see what it is actually supposed to be.)

The answer should have been `King Kong (3    )` - that is, **four** spaces and not one - but by rendering this in HTML (without `white-space: pre-wrap;` or a similar CSS rule), the whitespace was collapsed to one space.

The reason for there being four spaces is due to casting the number to `char(5)`, i.e. a five-character-long string. Since the number `3` will need only one character to be displayed, the remaining four characters in the string will be filled with spaces, so that the total length of `3`     is still five characters as it was specified.